# error for input() function in python

Tags: python

I'm a Python newbie and I get the following error for the code...

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print(name)
```

Output:

```
G:\Code\Python>UserInput.py
What's your name? Jeremy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Code\Python\UserInput.py", line 3, in <module>
    name = input("What's your name? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Jeremy' is not defined
```

The code gets executed only if I replace the input() as raw_input... How do I get it to display the message just by including the input()? I get that it has got something to do with the Python Interpreter versions (I've got both python27 and python34 installed). How do I go on about that??

Comment: Why do you want it to work with only `input`? To rephrase, what is the problem with using `raw_input()` ?

Comment: If you are lazy to type 4 extra characters (`'raw_'`) , then you should only use python 3 instead of 2.

Comment: yeah... how do I set my default interpreter to python 3? I tried changing the path in the environment variables but nothing seems effective.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `input`, it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))` which will try to execute your input.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Use `raw_input` instead.